# Can be used push models in asp.net using c#

Tags: asp.net

I have show notification or alert on asp.net page based on database server data insertion, so I want to know if it is possible to do this task by push models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SignalR to send notifications from your web server to your clients: http://signalr.net/.

To send notifications from SQL Server to your web server, you can use the `SqlDependency` and `SqlCacheDependency` classes.

From the guidelines, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/9dz445ks(v=vs.110).aspx,

```
SqlDependency.Start(myConnectionString);

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ... FROM MyTable", connection))
    {
        SqlCacheDependency dependency = new SqlCacheDependency(command);
        // Refresh the cache after the number of minutes
        // listed below if a change does not occur.
        // This value could be stored in a configuration file.
        int numberOfMinutes = 3;
        DateTime expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(numberOfMinutes);

        Response.Cache.SetExpires(expires);
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);

        Response.AddCacheDependency(dependency);

        connection.Open();
    }
}
```

Comment: SqlDependency class can be used with SQL SERVER 2012?